# Where's the static reference?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I'm a beginner to LWJGL, but I'm trying to learn, point is, in the code I'm trying, It's telling me I'm making a static reference to a non-static method:

```
(float)DisplayMode.getWidth()/(float)      DisplayMode.getHeight(),
```

Full code is [here](http://pastebin.com/6QKSZt8C), line 91 is giving me the error.
 Can anyone tell me how to fix it and what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code concerned. The easier you make it for people to answer, the more likely you will get an answer. It's also important to consider how your question will look in the future, and pastebin links might chage or disappear, making this question useless.

Comment: You need a `DisplayMode` object.  The error message is pretty self-explanatory.  `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` are instance methods, not static methods, and they need an instance of `DisplayMode` to work with.  I don't know how to use LWJGL so I can't help you any further.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't thinking clearly while posting this, but I just now realized what it was trying to do and fixed it. I created a DisplayMode named displayMode and set the Display's DisplayMode to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 91 `DisplayMode.getWidth()` and `DisplayMode.getHeight()` are static method calls, but it seems these are not static methods.  Looking at the code snippets [here](http://wiki.lwjgl.org/index.php?title=LWJGL_Basics_5_%28Fullscreen%29), it seems like you're supposed to construct a `DisplayMode` object and call `Display.setDisplayMode()` to register the object you constructed.

As an aside, I don't see `DisplayMode` in [LWJGL's JavaDocs](http://javadoc.lwjgl.org/) - I could be looking in the wrong place, but are you perhaps using an outdated version of LWJGL?